# Pipe output of type file to grep in Batch Command similar to Unix (using doskey)

Tags: shell, batch-file, grep

I've created alias for viewing output of file

```
doskey vinfo=type %MY_FILE%
```

what i want to do is

```
vinfo | grep 'search_text'
```

But its showing the output of vinfo (file content), but not passing the output of that to grep. when i go to file location and do

```
type filename | grep 'search_text'
```

it works.

I thought i could do something like

```
sinfo = type %MY_FILE% | grep $*
```

But that doesn't work. what should be the right way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

```
doskey sinfo= for /f "tokens=* delims=" %a in ('findstr "search_text" "%my_file%"') do @set "sinfo=%a"
```

then you can use `set my_file=someFile.txt` and call `sinfo`.The result will be saved in `%sinfo%` variable.

Comment: I want to use this in command line, not within the shell scripts, so i want to pass parameter for search text, and output should be displayed in console.

Comment: Also another issue my file location contains spaces so it says can't open file, since its breaking the location.

Comment: @Dineshkumar - have you tested this? it's for command line usage and should deal with the spaces.

Comment: yes i did, D:\First Folder\Info.txt the it tries to open Folder\info.txt and thats ofcourse not available.

Comment: @Dineshkumar try with `set "my_file=D:\First Folder\Info.txt"`

Comment: didn't help. still it breaks the location and fails

Comment: @Dineshkumar are you sure you defined the sinfo macro as its written.I've tested it with spaces and works.Be sure there are quotes here `"%my_file%"`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70687/discussion-between-dineshkumar-and-npocmaka).